# Install WIX Toolset On MAC OS And Create MSI

Tags: .net, msbuild, wix

I have a WIX project and I can create an MSI for the project on windows system.

But, is there a way to create the MSI using WIX on MAC [Install WIX on MAC]. I know MSI's work on windows. I just need my MAC to create an MSI So, I can later use it on windows.

When I tried to do "dotnet msbuild" on my MAC, I get `"SampleApp.wixproj: error: Wix toolset build tools need's to be installed".`

I have tried working with docker to create the MSI with WIX, but I get few `unknown symbol` reference errors.

Comment: Format errors, change title

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, WiX doesn't work on a Mac.

While the components based on .NET could also work using mono (and therefore, mono's msbuild), important build steps rely on native windows windows functionality used via .NETs native interop - this involves libraries such as `msi.dll`, `cabinet.dll` etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this is still true. Wix 4 is very different than Wix 3. In addition, Microsoft now supports running .Net on macOS. Can anyone verify if Wix 4 and .Net 8 work on macOS to build Windows installers?

Comment: No, he's not wrong.  Run `dotnet tool install --global wix` on Mac and try to build a wxs file.  It'll tell you that MacOs isn't supported and anything after this point is undefined.  Might you get lucky with wine or something?  Maybe.  But WiX is about creating MSIs and has a very intimate relationship with the win32 api. Not all .net core libraries and apps can run on all platforms.